# How to store an eshell alias in `init.el`?

Tags: init-file, eshell

I like to keep my configuration as self-contained as possible, and I'm wondering whether there's a way to manage `eshell` aliases in my `.emacs` file. Is it possible to set up aliases with a function call kept in my `.emacs` rather than a separate file in `.emacs.d/eshell/aliases`?

The problem I am ultimately trying to solve is to get `ff` when entered in command position in `eshell` to reliably behave identically to `find-file`. *I am assuming that the easiest, most direct way to do this is an eshell alias*.

The alias below, with single quotes, exactly as written, does the trick and behaves like `find-file` does. I'm just trying to manage my aliases in the same place as the rest of my customization.

```
alias ff 'find-file $1'
```

---

Here are some attempted solutions to the problem that don't work and the steps to reproduce. The fact that they don't Just Work suggests to me that some work is needed to "wire up" a function so that it's usable from `eshell`.

#### Non-Solution 1, `eshell/ff` function

1. `$ emacs -q -no-site-file`
2. within emacs, `C-x b *scratch* C-m`
3. write wrapper function in scratch buffer.

```
(defun eshell/ff (&rest args)
  (apply #'find-file args))
```

4. `C-x h M-x eval-region C-m` then `C-g` to deselect
5. `C-h f` `eshell/ff` to verify that the function exists.
6. `M-x eshell C-m`
7. within `eshell`, type `find-file /etc/hosts` and visit the buffer. Then go back to eshell
8. within `eshell`, type `ff /etc/hosts`. The error message below shows us that `eshell` found our definition, but is *somehow* treating it differently than `find-file`.

```
~ $ ff /etc/hosts
Wrong number of arguments: (1 . 2), 0
```

#### Non-Solution 2 `(defalias 'ff 'find-file)`

1. `$ emacs -q -no-site-file`
2. within emacs, `C-x b *scratch* C-m`
3. write wrapper function in scratch buffer.

```
(defalias 'ff 'find-file)
```

4. `C-x h M-x eval-region C-m` then `C-g` to deselect
5. `C-h f` `eshell/ff` to verify that the function exists.
6. `M-x eshell C-m`
7. within `eshell`, type `find-file /etc/hosts` as before to verify that `find-file` still works
8. within `eshell`, type `ff /etc/hosts`. The error message is the same as in `Non-Solution 1`.

Comment: I can't reproduce your errors following Non-Solution 1 or 2. What Emacs version are you running? Perhaps you're hitting some bug that was fixed.

Comment: @npostavs ... 26.1 . I think I just mistyped `ff` by itself instead of `ff /etc/hosts` because now I can't reproduce it either. :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by @npostavs in a comment underneath the original question, the following solution proposed by the original poster *should* work -- at least in a current version of Emacs that is -- tested with Emacs 26.1:

```lisp
(defun eshell/ff (&rest args)
  (apply #'find-file args))
```

---

**Alternative Solution**:

```lisp
(defun eshell-add-aliases ()
"Doc-string."
  (dolist (var '(("ff" "find-file $1")
                 ("wget" "/Users/HOME/.0.data/.0.emacs/.0.macports/bin/wget $*")
                 ("cvs" "/Users/HOME/.0.data/.0.emacs/.0.macports/bin/cvs $*")
                 ("curl" "/Users/HOME/.0.data/.0.emacs/.0.macports/bin/curl $*")
                 ("git" "/Users/HOME/.0.data/.0.emacs/.0.macports/bin/git $*")))
    (add-to-list 'eshell-command-aliases-list var)))

(add-hook 'eshell-post-command-hook 'eshell-add-aliases)
```

Please be aware that this answer defies the admonishment in the doc-string. [Therefore, this solution is only for the rebellious / adventurous souls....]

```
eshell-command-aliases-list is a variable defined in ‘em-alias.el’.

Its value is

(("git" "/Users/HOME/.0.data/.0.emacs/.0.macports/bin/git $*")
 ("curl" "/Users/HOME/.0.data/.0.emacs/.0.macports/bin/curl $*")
 ("cvs" "/Users/HOME/.0.data/.0.emacs/.0.macports/bin/cvs $*")
 ("wget" "/Users/HOME/.0.data/.0.emacs/.0.macports/bin/wget $*")
 ("ff" "find-file $1"))

  This variable may be risky if used as a file-local variable.

Documentation:
A list of command aliases currently defined by the user.
Each element of this alias is a list of the form:

  (NAME DEFINITION)

Where NAME is the textual name of the alias, and DEFINITION is the
command string to replace that command with.

Note: this list should not be modified in your init file.
Rather, any desired alias definitions should be declared using
the ‘alias’ command, which will automatically write them to the
file named by ‘eshell-aliases-file’.
```

Comment: and it does work. I made a mistake when testing.

Answer (score 0):

eshell looks for its aliases in the directory specified by the `eshell-aliases-file` variable, which by default is `$HOME/.emacs.d/eshell/alias`

In that file, you can just write:

```
alias foo bar
```

Then, either start a new eshell instance, which will read in your aliases from the alias file on startup, or you can issue the `eshell-read-aliases-list` command from within eshell and it will re-read the alias file.